# Background worker and Functions

Tags: wpf, backgroundworker

I have a background worker. its working perfectly fine however i want to move the code that it runs out of the DoWork is this possible ?

```
    void NewWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> ReturnResults = new List<string>();
        BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

                ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("Select StatusCode from Win32_PingStatus where address = 'Metabox-PC'");
                ManagementObjectCollection objCollection = searcher.Get();
                foreach (ManagementObject Results in objCollection)
                {
                    ReturnResults.Add(Results["StatusCode"].ToString());
                }
                e.Result = ReturnResults;
                // Perform a time consuming operation and report progress.
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
    }
```

So where it is actually querieing WMI i want to be able to add what ever computer in there i like.

Is this possible ?

```
    public void StartBackgroundWorker()
    {

        BackgroundWorker NewWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
        NewWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(NewWorker_DoWork);
        NewWorker.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(NewWorker_ProgressChanged);
        NewWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(NewWorker_RunWorkerCompleted);
        NewWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;

        NewWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }
    void NewWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> ReturnResults = new List<string>();
        BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

                BackgroundWorkerOperations NewOperation = new BackgroundWorkerOperations();
                NewOperation.Operations(GlobalComputerName);

                e.Result = ReturnResults;
                // Perform a time consuming operation and report progress.
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
    }

    public class BackgroundWorkerOperations
    {
        public Operations(string ComputerNames)
        {
            ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("Select StatusCode from Win32_PingStatus where address = '" + ComputerNames + '");
            ManagementObjectCollection objCollection = searcher.Get();
            foreach (ManagementObject Results in objCollection)
            {
                ReturnResults.Add(Results["StatusCode"].ToString());
            }
            e.Result = ReturnResults;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Moving part of DoWork to other function and call that function in DoWork, your program will still do the same operation in DoWork. Anyway, in coding we usually cant be sure until we try. So just give your second code a try, it looks fine.